# @RequestParam is ignoring variables with a pipe

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, data-binding

I am calling `/path/to/search/mytable?filter=field1|value1,field2|value2

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path/do/{blar}/{foo}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<MyType> getTableData(@PathVariable("blar") String blar,
    @PathVariable("foo") String foo,
    @RequestParam(name= "filter", required = false) String filter,
    @RequestParam(name= "sort", required = false) String sort) {
```

but for some reason having a pipe "|" in the text means that it doesn't get matched. Can someone help me understand what is going on?

I tried converting `filter` to `String[]` but if there is an pipe the whole thing is ignored and I get 400 back from the service.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Is there any chance the `filter` query string is not getting url-encoded? -- or just not properly url-encoded? ... just trying to cross off the easy-to-fix ones first ;)

edit: to expand on that, you'll want to see `%7C` in the url for the "pipe" character. There's a chance you'll have to url-encode the `filter` parameter separately from the url as a whole ... I've had cases like that in certain libraries making calls to an api.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. However I also wanted to know why it was happening. I know that Spring does some magic with commas if the destination type is `String[]` but that doesn't apply here. So if Spring doing something funny with pipes?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to tell you for certain; however, if the original url contained invalid characters, a 400 response may be Spring's default response.